# matching different number formats

Tags: xslt

I've the below lines in my XML.

```
<toc-item num="(i)">
<toc-item num="(ii)">
<toc-item num="(a)">
<toc-item num="(b)">
<toc-item num="1">
<toc-item num="2">
```

I need a xslt code that will give 3 if the number is in format(i), 2 if format in (a) and 1 for the last case. I've tried the below. But it is giving 2 in case if (i) or (a).

```
<xsl:variable name="nu">
  <xsl:number format="(i)" level="any" />
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="Brac">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains(current()/@num,$nu)">
      <xsl:value-of select="3"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="contains(current()/@num,'(')">
      <xsl:value-of select="2"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value of select="$Brac"/>
```

Please let me know how i can get it.

Thanks

Comment: This can elegantly be handled in XSLT 2.0. Are you allowed to use that?

Comment: yes i can use xslt 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<numbers>
  <toc-item num="(i)"/>
  <toc-item num="(ii)"/>
  <toc-item num="(a)"/>
  <toc-item num="(b)"/>
  <toc-item num="1"/>
  <toc-item num="2"/>
  <toc-item num="(2.x)"/>
</numbers>
```

the following XSLT 2.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template name="get_number_type">
    <xsl:param name="number_string"/>

    <xsl:analyze-string select="$number_string" regex="(^[0-9]+$)|(^\([a-h]\)$)|(^\([ivx]+\)$)">

      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="regex-group(1) != ''">
            <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="regex-group(2) != ''">
            <xsl:text>2</xsl:text>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="regex-group(3) != ''">
            <xsl:text>3</xsl:text>
          </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:matching-substring>

      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:text>invalid</xsl:text>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>

    </xsl:analyze-string>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="toc-item">
    <xsl:text>The number format of string '</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@num"/>
    <xsl:text>' is </xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="get_number_type">
      <xsl:with-param name="number_string" select="@num"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces the text output

```
The number format of string '(i)' is 3.
The number format of string '(ii)' is 3.
The number format of string '(a)' is 2.
The number format of string '(b)' is 2.
The number format of string '1' is 1.
The number format of string '2' is 1.
The number format of string '(2.x)' is invalid.
```

Notes:

- You may even want to turn the template into an XSLT 2.0 function which would make calling the helper functionality easier.
- Roman numbers are a little difficult when your letter enumeration exceeds the letter "h". The regular expression provided only works up to there and only for Roman numbers consisting of the digits "i", "v", and "x".
- If you have even more number formats there is a more generic way to implement the decoding as a `<xsl:for-each>` with the available number formats as an XML sub tree input. If you are interested in this, let me know.
- The regular expression currently does not tolerate preceding or following white space.

Comment: The solution was updated to handle the case in which the number format is not valid. Also, the regular expression was extended to explicitly check for the start (`^`) and the end (`$`) of the number string.